# ROS top level CMakelists.txt is not used, how to give cmake defaults for all sub projects?

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have a workspace set out as in the [ROS REP 128](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html) aka:

```
catkin_ws
   src
      CMakeLists.txt // < 1.
      project_1
          CMakeLists.txt
      project_2
          CMakeLists.txt
      ...
```

In fact you can reproduce this using just the catkin tutorials [here](https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/tree/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws). The top level `CMakeLists.txt` (`1.` in the example above) appears to not be sourced. I can tell this because i added the line, `weifnbwefn` to the end of it expecting a cmake error (on a clean build) but got none.

To reproduce this:

1. Clone the above repo.
2. Navigate to the `catkin_tutorials/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws`
3. Modify the `src/CMakeLists.txt` with something that won't build.
4. Build with `catkin build`

So this leads to 2 questions:

1. Why is this file not used?
2. How can i add default cmake items for all of my sub projects? for eg. if i wanted to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` for every sub-project?

---

For 2. , i know that i can add additional cmake args to my build profile in `.catkin_tools` but for anything more complex then a couple of arguments, this would not be scaleable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Could you add the parameters you used to run cmake with to do the initial configuration (as well as the working directory in case you use relative paths)?

Comment: BTW: Assuming by "subprojects" you mean directories containing `CMakeLists.txt` files other than the toplevel one that are added via `add_subdirectory`: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` should do the trick as long as it's done before `add_subdirectory`; every directory has it's own variable scope but a read access falls back to the scope of the "parent directory" (refering to the relationship established by `add_subdirectory` here), if the variable is not present in the scope of the current dir. Target properties have higher priority though and subdirectories can overwrite the value.

Comment: @fabian I added some reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My understanding from the docs](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html) is that the `src/CMakeLists.txt` is intended to be a symlink to `catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` in the ROS installation and not be edited. It is only used if CMake is driving the legacy build workflow.

The new workflow, which `catkin build` implements, ignores this file specifically to isolate the builds and prevent cross-talk from one package setting CMake cache variables another reads.

So that answers part (1), but regrettably I am not experienced enough with catkin to know what the best practice is to store common configuration. I do know that there is a `--cmake-args` flag to `catkin build` that you could use in tandem with the `CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE` variable to inject a CMake file containing your settings.

For C++17 specifically, this would look like:

```
$ catkin build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
```

See the docs for this here: https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html#temporarily-changing-build-flags